# RadGrid Get Selected Row Index from Item Template Button

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am working on a project using Telerik controls. I'm trying to figure out how to get the selected row index on an ItemTemplate button click event, like in the markup below:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" 
    DataSourceID="cusGrid" GridLines="None" Skin="Default" AllowPaging="True" DataKeyValue="CustomerID" 
    PageSize="500" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" ShowStatusBar="true" >
        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="cusGrid">
            <RowIndicatorColumn>
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </RowIndicatorColumn>
            <ExpandCollapseColumn>
                <HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
            </ExpandCollapseColumn>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="CheckBoxTemplateColumn">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="SelRecord" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    ...
```

Normally with a `GridView` I would just do something like:

```
protected void SelRecord(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var gRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as Control).Parent.Parent;
    var key = string.Empty;
    if (gRow != null) { key = gRow.Cells[0].Text; }
}
```

What is the equivalent with the Telerik control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CommandName=""` instead of `OnClick`.

Also add `onitemdatabound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound"` to the main telerik:RadGrid tag.

Then in the code behind:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridDataItem)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = e.Item as GridDataItem;

                int selectedRowIndex = dataItem.RowIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see that this was excepted as the answer, but can you please explain what this is doing to fix the issue?

Answer (score 8):

Use the `CommandArgument`, and use `OnCommand` instead of `OnClick` to get the row index:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%#Container.ItemIndex%>' OnCommand="Button1_Command" ... />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Button1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridDataItem item = RadGrid1.Items[(int)e.CommandArgument];
}
```

Comment: Agreed on this method it's by far the simplest way.

Comment: take care about   cast to int try :      RadGrid1.Items[int.parse((e.CommandArgument.ToString())];

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the [Telerik documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-selecting-row-with-checkbox-server-side.html), it looks like you want:

```
var gRow = ((sender as Button).NamingContainer as GridItem).Selected;
```

You didn't ask about this piece, but I think this code:

```
if (gRow != null) { key = gRow.Cells[0].Text; }
```

is asking for trouble.

Although markup and code-behind are always highly coupled, directly referencing individual cells is a code smell if you ask me. I'm guessing that you want to pull "Select" out of the ASP `Button` in your `ItemTemplate`.

Can you assign an ID to your `Button`, and call `FindControl("buttonID")` to get the data you need? That will help keep your code more maintainable and readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="IndexRow" HeaderText="#">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%#Container.ItemIndex + 1%>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks This is what I was looking for... do the same without any change in code behind :)

Answer (score 0):

something like this in Button click event should work

```
        foreach (GridDataItem item in RadGrid1.SelectedItems)
        {
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)RadGrid1.SelectedItems;
            var key = string.Empty;
            key = item.ItemIndex;
        }
```